# How do i copy webdynpro application into a text file

Tags: abap, webdynpro

I am copying my abap/ooabap code into text file.
How do i copy a webdynpro applicaton this way.
I don't want to use transport requests.

Comment: ...why? "How do I use $WRONG_TOOL to do $UNSPECIFIED_JOB?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is not possible as with normal programs. If you do not want to use transport requests, the default way is using [SAPlink](https://www.assembla.com/spaces/saplink/wiki).